# Examples of manifolds (not) being: flat, homogeneous and isotropic

Tags: spacetime, symmetry, curvature

I am looking for (at least) one example of the following manifolds:

1. Flat, homogeneous and isotropic
2. Curved, homogeneous and isotropic
3. Flat, non-homogeneous and isotropic
4. Flat, homogeneous and non-isotropic
5. Curved, non-homogeneous and isotropic
6. Curved, homogeneous and non-isotropic
7. Flat, non-homogeneous and non-isotropic
8. Curved, non-homogeneous and non-isotropic

By isotropic, I mean isotropic at least about some specific point.

This is what comes to (my) mind:

1. Euclidean space
2. (2-)Sphere
3. Euclidean space with one point removed / Vector space
4. Minkowski space
5. Sphere with one point removed?
6. ?
7. Euclidean space with two point removed?
8. A generic manifold

I hope you can provide some better examples.

Comment: An example of 6 would be a rotating cosmological spacetime: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1048/

Comment: If a space is flat, then it is isomorphic to a space with all $\pm 1$ along the diagonals.  Under usual assumptions, your only choices are Minkowski and Euclidean space.  So 4 and 7 are the empty set, unless you play games global topology and use that as an excuse for anisotropy.

Comment: I sincerely hope that if anyone answers this comprehensively, then she/he does so in the form of a table as opposed to a list.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: Shouldn't Minkowski space be considered anisotropic since it has a light-cone structure and therefore a preferred (time-like) direction?

Comment: @LittleBrownOne: usually people don't talk about spacetimes as being isotropic or not, just spaces.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: ok, fair enough. But, do you agree with my observation that if we were to talk about isotropy of spacetime, then the Minkowski space time would be anisotropic?

Comment: @LittleBrownOne: yes, but it's kind of boringly so.

Comment: @Jerry Perhaps to you :-)