# Does the Universe spin?

Tags: cosmology, angular-momentum, universe

Maybe it's a stupid question, so I will delete it if it will receive too many down votes but..

I was wondering about the Universe, and the fact that

- We know it's expanding;
- We don't know if it has an edge, maybe yes maybe no;

But.. does the Universe spin? If we should describe the entire observable Universe as a "body", we should take into account its expansion but would it be also described as a rotating body or as a non-rotating one?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1048/50583

Comment: The Universe is a totality, if it was spinning what would it be spinning relative to ?There is no outside Frame of Reference, or co-ordinate system.  No observer can be present 'outside' the Universe.

Comment: @ACuriousMind thank youuuu!! Very interesting link!!

Answer (score -2):

The universe is constantly expanding, but not rotating. It would be possible for our universe to spin if there were several other universes orbiting in a system of their own, but that answer is in the perspective of how our solar system's planets rotate.

There are so many possibilities, but not enough definite answers.

Comment: A better question may be " Is there a preferred rotation axis for all the galaxies. When you look, they all appear to be in random orientation but is there a preferred orientation for the galaxies?"