# Was the big bang singularity rotating?

Tags: cosmology, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, universe, big-bang

See, I was thinking that every atom has electrons rotating around the nucleus and there are huge number of atoms in the universe, according to law of conservation of angular momentum, it remains conserved so where does all that angular momentum come from?

Answer (score 2):

Angular momentum is a vector (actually a [pseudovector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector)) and that means angular momentum adds like vectors do. So if two atoms have the same angular momentum but pointing in opposite directions those two angular momenta will add up to zero. This means the total angular momentum of the universe can be zero even though individual objects within it have non-zero angular momenta.

As to whether the whole universe does or doesn't have a net angular momentum, this is covered by the answers to [What if the universe is rotating as a whole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/what-if-the-universe-is-rotating-as-a-whole)