# Spacetime drag and galaxies' radial velocity mismatch

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, galaxy-rotation-curve, frame-dragging

We know - or theorize - that a spinning black hole drags spacetime in its surroundings, producing measurable effects on the accretion disk (the minimum stable orbit radius).
What I cannot grasp is why this isn't the case for a rotating galaxy.
Why the mismatch in classical rotational velocity predictions isn't explained from the spacetime dragging of the total mass of the galaxy at a given radius value?
Why do we need dark matter to adjust for the "strange" measurements?

Comment: OP seems to be mixing relativistic and non-relativistic effects.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/362097/

Answer (score 1):

The spacetime dragging is only significant very close to the event horizon of a spinning black hole i.e. within a few Schwarzschild radii. While in principle the effect exists for a rotating galaxy in practice it is so small as to be completely undetectable.