# Will a muon decay in an empty universe?

Tags: special-relativity, time

Imagine, a deep empty universe consisting of only one particle muon. Will it decay?

As there isn't any change in its surroundings and thus time will lose its meaning. But if the muon will decay in that situation, doesn't it prove that time is something deeper than our experience or what a clock shows!

Comment: I think this is somewhat more philosophical than physics...

Comment: Sorry if you found it so. But no, I don't think so. It questions aout the existence of time itself! If muon decays in an unchanging universe then time is something independent of change! And if not then time would be proved to be just a mathematical abstraction!

Comment: It is a valid physics question. [See How does an isolated electron in deep space 'know' it is spinning?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537568/37364) Thought experiments are common. It is equivalent to asking what causes a muon to decay? Do the surroundings matter? What if there are no surroundings?

Comment: @mmesser314 yes that's what my point is! To understand how nature works!

Comment: *Imagine, a deep empty universe consisting of only one particle muon. Will it decay?* This is untestable.

Comment: Go with Jonas and G. Smith.

Considering any aspect of a single anything in an otherwise empty universe is less susceptible to any kind of analysis than pin-dancing or even navel gazing.

If those are your standards, so be it…

Comment: @G.Smith: If the answer is "No" I have a plausible engineering use for it. It's just hard to test, not untestable.

Comment: Nobody knows, of course.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin we have lots of spherical cows in a vacuum (e.g. a hydrogen atom in QM), the abstraction from the surroundings doesn't make them unuseful.

Comment: @Joshua You have an otherwise empty universe available to be engineered?

Comment: @chepner: No, but does not decay in an empty universe is ~= requires interaction with another particle to decay. This means we can send muons down a long sealed vacuum tube with helium-cooled walls at a range far beyond their normal decay range.

Comment: Define "empty".

Comment: @Ruslan Then goto Hearth, please.

Answer (score 16):

This question seems to be based on a perception of a muon as a sort of little entity sitting in otherwise empty space. But that is not the universe as it is described by physics. The universe is full everywhere of all the various fields of the Standard Model (or of some more sophisticated model which subsumes the Standard Model). Once you have that universe then you have decay of muons. But if you are thinking of some other set of physical ideas then you are not talking about muons. You are using the same word to refer to some other thing. In that case what it will do will depend on what it is and what behaviours are open to it. But since this has not been described, no answer is possible.

If the question is merely pointing out that the concept of development over time requires that there be the possibility of change, then of course that is true. It has been pointed out since antiquity. Perhaps it was first noticed and pondered in the paleolithic period; I don't know.

Comment: I don't have knowledge that radioactive process happen because of the interaction with quantum fields.... So may you please clarify, whether the interaction of a particle with a quantum field happen instantaneously?

Comment: @SwayamJha A particle is a way of talking about a state of excitation of a field. With interacting fields, each particle such as muon involves a combination of all the fields which can interact with it. It is a bit like a localised bump or wave on a membrane, only there are many membranes involved, all interacting together. Complex but rather beautiful!

Comment: Wait, but modern conception of time does not require any change at all. Energy eigenstates exist and time does not cease to exist when a system is in an energy eigenstate. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 8):

Physics is fundamentally an experimental science. The laws of physics are based on experiments, all of which are conducted in this universe. We have no access to sterile universes like the one described in the question in order to test theories about such universes, and we have no indication that the results of experiments in such universes would be informative regarding the physics of our universe.

All we can say is that according to the laws of physics in our universe isolated muons decay at an intrinsic proper rate that appears to be unaffected by any external consideration.

Comment: Will motion affect the decay process in a "pre-relativistic" physics?

Comment: The muon was discovered in 1936, well after both special and general relativity were developed. The standard model is relativistic, and is the only accepted theory I am aware of describing muon decay.

Comment: Actually my friend argues, that the decay is affected by the motion independently- disregarding the fact that time dikates for moving object. So what's yiur opinion?

Comment: My opinion is that is a separate question and should be asked as a separate question. I don't know of a non-relativistic theory of muon decay that could be used to answer the question, so I won't be able to respond.

Comment: Does the $y$ axis lose all meaning if all you have is a horizontal line? All you describe is $f(t) = some constant$. Most likely the muon will exist as both decayed and intact until the universe interacts with something else. But that would violate the *no event* criteria of your question. So the question itself is oxymoronic. "Is there change in an unchanging universe?"

Comment: @SwayamJha: The observed decay-time depends on the relative motion of the observer to the particle, due to special relativity. However the decay-time in the muon's frame of reference (the so-called "proper time") is constant, regardless of the motion of other things in the universe. So in an empty universe, only the muon's proper time would be measured, because there are no observers in other reference frames to measure anything else.

Answer (score 5):

We happen to live in a universe where today we know space is throughout permeated by quantum fields, which includes the respective field of the muon, and its decay products, the electron and neutrinos. You can think of the muon as the excitation of its respective field, a manifestation of energy stored in the quantum field. This form of energy can transform into other forms of energy if the laws of physics allows. Since to our knowledge the laws allow for the muon to decay, it will do so at a certain probability, and will transform into its decay products.

> Muon decay almost always produces at least three particles, which must include an electron of the same charge as the muon and two types of neutrinos.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon

Since vacuum is not empty, and quantum fields can couple to each other, the muon can transform into other forms of excitations in other fields.

> We think about particle decay in terms of couplings of quantum fields to each other: an excitation in one field can decay into excitations in others.

[Why are muons considered to be elementary particles in the Standard Model?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274858/why-are-muons-considered-to-be-elementary-particles-in-the-standard-model)

You say time will lose its meaning in an otherwise empty universe, but I do not think time will lose its meaning, since the muon itself is a quantum mechanical clock if you will.

Since the quantum fields permeate all of space, including the deepest intergalactic voids of space, this decay will happen everywhere in the universe, even in an empty region (and I assume your question is about this), where no other forms of clusters of matter exist, even as your question states, not even a single other particle (excitation). Bottom line, the void of empty space is not empty, it is permeated by all the quantum fields, and since to our knowledge the laws of physics are the same everywhere in the known universe, this together with the probabilistic nature of QM is enough for the decay to happen.

Answer (score 4):

As already said if there is no other quantum field in your universe then the muon will not decay. You have to keep in mind that a quantum field fills the entire universe and that the muon is nothing but an excitation of the muon/anti-muon field. Now if there are the other known quantum fields in your universe, then the muon will decay, even if the other fields don't have any excitation. Now theoretically time is two things:

1. In general relativity, time is the dimension that always goes in one direction and is an entity just like space that preexists all things and will be there even if there is nothing inside.
2. In quantum mechanics time is a parameter just as in Newtonian mechanics and it acts on things that experience it.

If there is one field with one excitation in the universe then we have two answers. First, we can say that time flows on it but the muon will not decay because there is no coupling with any other field, this is the relativistic point of view. Secondly one can reasonably say that since there is only one thing in the universe, and because it does not seem to depend on time, then time is a useless parameter and then drop it from the equations.

Now you can describe a decay without "time". In fact, you can organize all the possible initial and final states of the fields in whatever order you like and with any type of labels, you will be able to have the same result as with "time": saying that a state is an initial or final state is a statement for the physicist because mathematically all that matters is a $|\Psi\rangle$ and a $\langle \Psi'|$. We organize them from past to future because this is what we experience every day, but in the end, all that matters is transitions from one state to another.

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't it decay normally? If you assert that an external clock is needed, you can imagine *two* muons. One can be the clock for the other. Will they decay?

- If so, when? What is the clock for the first of them to decay?
- If not, then what about a lot of muons? Is our universe as a whole any different? What is the external clock for our universe?

The natural clock for muon decay is the timescale determined by our fundamental constants.

Comment: Will motion affects the decay process in a "pre-relativistic" physics?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't such a thing as "otherwise empty space".

If the quantum fields that permeate spacetime, permit only muons, and no decay to anything else, then only muons can exist.

If they permit anything else, eventually some muons will decay (tunnel, transform...) Into some of those other things.

Or at least, that's our best current understanding........

Answer (score 2):

Does this other universe consist of other quantum fields (e.g. electrons, neutrinos, W bosons)? I don’t think this is really the intent of your question, but if those fields *do* exist and there is something for the muon to decay to (and something to decay through), then there isn’t a reason to think it wouldn’t decay.

Comment: No in that universe atleast locwlly no such field exist!

Comment: If there is nothing for the muon to decay into, then it won’t decay. That is why electrons are stable in our universe and why R-parity conserving SUSY models have a dark matter candidate. This doesn’t say much about your initial question about time though.

Comment: So basically, a muon decays because it's affected by its surroundings?

Comment: I wouldn’t say that, no. You said there were no “local” quantum fields but you can’t turn off fields like that, they exist everywhere. It doesn’t have to do with the muons surroundings, just that the muon has something to decay into. Any particle that *can* decay, *will* decay eventually.

Comment: What do I mean by surroundings is quantum fields only. So cnclusively, the reason for decay to happen is the particle's interaction with a quantum field?

Comment: Yes, muons couple to other fields and therefore can interact and decay (muon -> W- +muon_neutrino, W- -> e + e_antineutrino)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119975/discussion-between-swayam-jha-and-schoppe).

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the [“If a tree falls in a forest ...”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest) question, and, just like that question, it is a philosophical question and not a scientific one. That is not a value judgement - there are many interesting and important questions that simply are not amenable to scientific analysis.

If the universe is truly empty apart from one muon then we can never know whether it will decay or not because there can be nothing else in the universe to observe the muon. Not only is the question beyond our current state of knowledge, it is fundamentally unanswerable in a scientific sense.

The muon may decay, or it may not decay, or it may exist in a superposition of undecayed and decayed states, or it may turn into a small pink unicorn. There is absolutely no way of knowing.

Answer (score 1):

This question can be generalized to whether or not anything can "happen" in empty [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) where there are no external indications of time progressing. If you were to look at the muon's world line in an empty universe or a non-empty universe, the result at a certain point along that line will always be the same (assuming it doesn't interact with anything before that point). It doesn't matter if you're looking at the time dimension or one of the three spacial dimensions. This is true for anything, not just muons.

Answer (score 0):

A muon is a kind of clock  in relativity theory.  But in an empty universe there would be no other clock to compare it to  and no relativity. . Without relativity  the universe as we know it is not defined and cannot exist.The answer to your question is therefore no