# How come everything in the universe except the universe itself are spinning?

Tags: cosmology, angular-momentum, reference-frames, universe, machs-principle

The planets and stars are spinning, galaxies and clusters are spinning so shouldnt the universe also spin? I think objects spin is to preserve angular momentum but it must also implied that in the beginning everything should be spinning too so is the big bang I guess, no? Then my next question is how does the big bang gets spinning if that's the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if the universe is rotating as a whole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1048/)

Comment: @BenCrowell: just completed sagnac effect course so unless starlight from 2 known sources in the opposite direction produce fringe, we know the universe is not spinning right? and in order to proof that we must also know the universe axis too so this is impossible i think i get it ;D

Comment: Moreover in a perhaps spatially infinite universe does the idea of a rotation axe even hold?? I don't think so but I am just thinking stimulated by Q and comments