# Could the source of dark energy be the universe rotating in a higher dimension?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, rotational-kinematics, dark-energy

As I understand it, the centrifugal force in a merry-go-round increases as we move further away from the center. Could the universe be spinning in a higher dimension (or even just spinning in a combination of the existing space-time ones)? If so, would that account for the acceleration in the expansion of the universe (aka Dark energy)?

Comment: The answer here may address your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1048/

Comment: Thanks. It's going to take me a while to digest it. Will see whether it scratches my itch properly.